# How to use dynamic arguments in a dplyr filter within function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to add the ability to filter with a dynamic number of variables within dplyr. I want the user to be able to enter commands in a simple fashion within the function call i.e. `...` - the example below should help. The user should be able to segment out `seg1 == 'b'` and `seg2 == 'd'` by simply entering them into the function `my_func(example_data, seg1 = 'b', seg2 = 'd')` but all attempts have failed. This is easy to do with standard SQL, just not familiar with NSE formatting.

```
library('tidyverse')

example_data = tibble(seg1 = c('a','b','b','c'),
                      seg2 = c('d', 'd', 'd', 'e'),
                      out = c(1, 10, 20, 40))

my_func = function(dat, ...){
  args = list(...)
  arg_names = names(args)
  ### ????
  dat = dat %>%
    filter(???)
  ### ????
  return(dat)
}

my_func(example_data, seg1 = 'b', seg2 = 'd')

# Desired output
> example_data %>% filter(seg1 == 'b', seg2 == 'd')
# A tibble: 2 x 3
seg1  seg2    out
<chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 b     d        10
2 b     d        20
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't ask me to explain this, because most of **rlang** is still indescribably obtuse to me. I figured this out by randomly trying things.

```
my_func = function(dat, ...){
  args <- rlang::enexprs(...)
  dat %>%
    filter(!!! args)
}

> my_func(example_data, seg1 == 'b', seg2 == 'd')
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  seg1  seg2    out
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 b     d        10
2 b     d        20
```

Note the use of `==`, so we're passing expressions to `...`, not named arguments.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to change those named parameters into equality filters, here another alternative.

```
my_func = function(dat, ...){
  args <- enquos(...)
  ex_args <- unname(imap(args, function(expr, name) quo(!!sym(name)==!!expr)))

  dat %>% filter(!!!ex_args)
}

my_func(example_data, seg1 = 'b', seg2 = 'd')
```